# Compute the Stationary Distribution of Infinite-state Markov Chain

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, markov-chains

I am asked to compute the stationary distribution of the markov chain with state space $E=\{0,1,2,\ldots,\}$ and transition matrix $P$ below:
$$\begin{matrix}
\beta_1 & \beta_2 & H_1 & H_2 & H_3 & \cdots & H_k & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots \\
\omega & \beta_3 & H_0 & H_1 & H_2 & \cdots & \cdots & H_k & 0 & 0 & \cdots \\
0& \omega & \beta_3 & H_0 & H_1 & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & H_k & 0  & \cdots \\
0 & 0& \omega & \beta_3 & H_0  & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & H_k & \cdots \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots\\
\end{matrix}$$
Elements of $P$ are constants. I use $\pi P = \pi$ as well as $\sum_{i=0}^\infty \pi_i =1$. However, I cannot get the closed-form of $\pi_i$. Can anyone help me to finish this? Thanks.

Comment: Here the $\beta_i$, $\omega$, and $H_j$ are presumed constants?

Comment: @Math1000 Yes. They are all constants.